# Prolog, family-tree how to say they are bastards

Tags: prolog, family-tree

For example if I have this ancestors, how can I say who is the bastard son or daughter?

```
ancestor(frank,mary).
ancestor(frank,andrew).
ancestor(frank,jake).
ancestor(joanne,mary).
ancestor(joanne,andrew).

married(frank,joanne).
```

laws  (there are some more code that I am not posting because it is no relevant)

```
mother(X,Y) :- ancester(X,Y),gender(X,female).
father(X,Y) :- ancester(X,Y),gender(X,male).

son(X,Y) :- father(Y,X).

sister(X,Y) :- ancester(Z,X),ancester(Z,Y),X\==Y,gender(Y,female).
brother(X,Y) :- ancester(Z,Y),ancester(Z,X), X\==Y,gender(Y,male).

grandfahter(X,Y) :- ancester(X,Z),ancester(Z,Y),gender(X,male).
grandmother(X,Y) :- ancester(X,Z),ancester(Z,Y),gender(X,female).
```

Comment: By the definition of "bastard," I would think you'd need some facts indicating who is married to whom. You really can't tell who the "bastards" are just by sireship which is all your facts show.

Comment: @lurker  I have edited, and said: married(frank,joanne).

Comment: Good, so now you can tell if someone is a bastard (their parents aren't married). For example, `bastard(X) :- father(F, X), mother(M, X), \+ married(F, M).`

Comment: @lurker thanks, appreciate your help!

Comment: does it exists another way instead probably of   "\+" beacause it is giving me this error:

`bastard(X) :- father(F, X), mother(M, X), \+ married(F, M).
syntax error in parser `                        @lurker

Comment: @AlfonsoPinto what Prolog are you using? The `\+` is ISO, so it should work in any ISO compliant Prolog. Are you sure the error is pointing to that code? It works in GNU Prolog and in SWI Prolog. Check for typing errors.

Comment: SWI-Prolog also supports `not` but indeed, the newer code should use `\+`.

Comment: indeed, I used `not` and it worked! @AlexanderSerebrenik

Answer (score 0):

Just to summarise the answer to this question based on the comments.

Assuming that the person is a bastard if their parents aren't married, one can write

`bastard(X) :- father(F, X), mother(M, X), \+ married(F, M).`

If your Prolog dialect does not support `\+` (despite of it being in the ISO standard), you should use `not`:

`bastard(X) :- father(F, X), mother(M, X), not(married(F, M)).`